# Length of string displayed using tkinter different from length in microsoft word/pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, fonts

I am using tkinter to allow a user to input a text string, do some manipulations and then copy and paste the string into ms-word or a fillable pdf. The location it is being pasted to uses Times New Roman 12 pt font. It is important that the length of the string in times 12 is not too long for the fillable field in the pdf, so I thought I could use font.measure() from tkinter to measure how long the font will be when pasted into the document.

However, I have noticed some discrepancies with how long a string is in tkinter (in times 12) versus how long a string is in ms-word or a pdf (in times 12). Pictures below show what I am talking about:

Differing lengths:
[image]

Same lengths:
[image]

Why is this happening? Is there a way to make it consistent?

Please note that when I refer to lengths I am NOT talking about number of characters. Obviously that is consistent. I care about the length of the text when rendered in a specific font and size.

Code for text entrybox:

```
Entry(self.frame, width=100, font="Times 12")
```

Comment: The one that has a different length has a different font size. The m's are visibly smaller.

Comment: No font sizes were changed from one to the other. The only difference is the string that was copied into the text box.

Comment: Well the font is visibly smaller in your screen shots. You may need to use a text field instead of an entry field to keep the relative size the same.

Comment: Where did you get the "how to change the font" from as we would like to contact that web site or person and have it changed to the correct method or there will be more questions like this http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-styling.htm

Comment: @Mike - SMT, Regardless of how it looks, you should be able to see from the second picture that the font sizes are not the issue. Those two lines line up almost perfectly.

Comment: @CurlyJoe, I don't follow. The link you provided seems to indicate (font = "Times 12") is appropriate.

Comment: Windows has a number of rendering technologies, and they aren't always consistent. It's unrealistic to hope that two programs will render identically.

Comment: @MarkRansom So there's no way to make them render the same way?

Comment: I can't say without knowing the details of how each program renders, but it's unlikely given your evidence so far.

Comment: Based on Mark Ransom's comments it seems as if tkinter renders the font differently from MS Word. There would not appear to be an easy way to make them consistent.